# Interaction with a subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am trying to automate the running of a program called `selftest.exe`, which when it is done, asks the user to press `[ENTER]` to exit. Thus, calling this process through `subprocess.Popen` does not work, since it hangs forever until the user presses `[ENTER]`, which he never will.

Whilst I don't think it would be reasonably possible to send the key stroke at the exact right time, I thought about a timeout, like "after XXX seconds, send "\n" and store the stdout of the process in a string", with XXX being big enough for me to have all the results.

Is that a viable idea, or is there a "cleaner" idea to work with interactive programs in general ?

Solution: the first answer is right, the program will quit, whenever you press enter. However, calling `p.communicate(input='\n')` will lead to the following error : **'str' does not support the buffer interface**. It needs to be `p.communicate(input=b'\n')` instead.

Comment: Did you try [process.communicate('\n')](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a silly question, and you've probably done this already, but are you sure simply sending the "\n" to the process won't work? I would say it's likely that `selftest.exe` doesn't actually read the `[ENTER]` until it's done. That, of course, depends on how the programs reads the enter. You may also try sending `SIGQUIT` or `SIGTERM`, so *maybe* the program will handle them gracefully.

Comment: Windows doesn't support POSIX signals (except for the 6 that C requires). So `os.kill(pid, signum)` for any `signum`, except `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` or `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`, just attempts a crude `TerminateProcess`. There's nothing graceful about it.

Comment: You're right. When I wrote that I forgot that the user was in Windows (which was obvious with the `.exe` file), sorry about that.